# Is There Any Solution To Check a Webpage is Mobile Friendly (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, mobile, responsive-design

I was wondering since most of the websites use responsive themes or mobile friendly is there any solution to check whether a given url is mobile friendly or not programmatically.

Similar solution exist within google (manual) -  https://www.google.co.uk/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

Do you guys have any ideas on possible solutions ?

Comment: Check if this link helps you: http://blog.shaharia.com/google-mobile-friendly-test-in-php/

Comment: @David Taiaroa i am checking it now

Comment: Hi, FYI I had it working well for me in PHP

Comment: @DavidTaiaroa I tried your link but the results it's giving is desktop speed not anything like mobile speed or mobile friendly although visual one gives mobile speed but api is not showing it.

Comment: Hi, I've added more details below about what I know so far.  "it's not (giving) anything like mobile speed " ...  hmmm, I don't see where this is shown @ https://www.google.co.uk/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/ . Maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

The following uses [this code from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/shahariaazam/73c0644c6b2f2cba5ca2#file-google-mobile-friendliness-test-php)

(1) get your Google API key from the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com)

(2) customise the following php code, or produce programatically. Note that at line 19 you'll need to use your own API key and enter your own URL

```
 <?php
    /**
     * @param $url
     * @param $apiKey
     * @return mixed
     */
    function isMobileReady($url, $apiKey)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?key='.$apiKey.'&url='.$url.'&strategy=mobile',
        ));
        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $resp;
    }
    //result as an array look for  ["pass"]=> bool(true) } or false
    $result = json_decode(isMobileReady('https://www.panchroma.ca/en/', 'AIzaSyDSrus1NcAIFXOWQjoAgwEOVChX_KEnhg_dummy_api_key'), true);
    var_dump($result);
```

(3) the pagespeed results are dumped to the screen, I think the most important info for the mobile friendly test result is near the top. Look for

```
{ ["USABILITY"]=> array(2) { ["score"]=> int(98) ["pass"]=> bool(true) } }
```

The score is your Google PageSpeed score [0-100] and the "pass" boolean is either true or false, true is equivalent to passing the [Mobile Friendly Test](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/)

Full credit [to this author](https://gist.github.com/shahariaazam)

===

## Update

In response to a question of how to test multiple URLs,  I have one suggestion below.
And [here's the live result](https://www.panchroma.ca/sandbox/mobile-test.php) .

This dumps a lot of stuff to the page, search for 'score' to see the mobile-friendly test results for the 3 sample URLs

```
<?php
    /**
     * @param $url
     * @param $apiKey
     * @return mixed
     */
    function isMobileReady($url, $apiKey)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?key='.$apiKey.'&url='.$url.'&strategy=mobile',
        ));
        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $resp;
    }

    $websites = array( "https://www.panchroma.ca/en/", "https://www.google.ca","https://www.youtube.com" );
    foreach($websites as $website) { 

        $result = json_decode(isMobileReady($website, 'AIzaSyDSrus1NcAIFXOWQjoAgwEOVChX_KEnhg_dummy_api_key'), true);
        var_dump($result);
    }

?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you confirm the that api url is working ? i am trying manually with my api and url but I am getting "Invalid value 'http://stackoverflow.com/''. Values must match the following regular expression: 'http(s)?://.*'

Comment: @AlstonAntony , I double checked and everything seems to work for me. To clarify, for the URL you want 'http://stackoverflow.com'  (with http:// , no quotes). To generate the API key, I created a new project, enabled the API, chose pagespeed insights API and then a server key, not sure how critical some of these steps are.

Comment: I have tried the above code .It is working .But I need to check for multiple websites at a same time.I have tried using form.It is working for only one website. It gives result for only last given  website. How to change the above code  for checking multiple websites at a same time using form .

Comment: @Revathi, did you try creating an array of the URLs you want to check? Then check each URL by looping through the array and outputting the results one by one?

Comment: $content = $_POST['content_name'];
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
  
  
    
 

       
    foreach($lines as  $line)
{
 
 $result = json_decode(isMobileReady($line, 'AIzaSyDSrus1NcAIFXOWQjoAgwEOVChX_KEnhg_dummy_api_key'), true);
 
 
 
 
 
    var_dump($result);
 
}
i have  replaced  google api  key and tried like this.It is giving  result for only last given result.I get the input from text area.

Comment: Hi @Revathi, thanks for your code. Please see my edit above, hopefully this will be helpful ;)

Comment: It is working.var_dump($result); displaying all the array values .I need to display only pass and avoid plugins values only.

Answer (score 0):

Acquire a PageSpeed Insights API KEY in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/pagespeedonline-json.googleapis.com/overview?project=citric-program-395&hl=pt-br&duration=P30D and create a credentials, follow the google's instructions.

Add in your project a reference for Newtonsoft.Json.

In C# (6.0) and .NET 4.5.2,  I did some like this:

```
String yourURL = "https://www.google.com.br";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = client.GetAsync($"/pagespeedonline/v3beta1/mobileReady?url={yourURL }&key=AIzaSyArsacdp79HPFfRZRvXaiLEjCD1LtDm3ww").Result;
string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
bool isMobileFriendly = obj.Value<JObject>("ruleGroups").Value<JObject>("USABILITY").Value<bool>("pass");
```